# grep patterns and keep matches on the same line

Tags: awk, grep, wildcards, pattern-matching

From the sample input:

```
cat file.txt
ID1    sample1    sample2    match1    sample3
ID2    sample4    match2     matchABC
```

I would like to obtain sample output, keeping only the matched words on the same line. In this case, I want to keep the ID* and the match*

```
cat file.txt
ID1    match1
ID2    match2     matchABC
```

Things I tried:

```
cat file.txt | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^match|ID/){print $i}}}'
```

I get the wanted match but not in the correct format (they're all in separate lines of the output). I tried grep with option `-o` and multiple patterns but the match is also printed on separate lines, as [expected behaviour](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you don't REALLY want to have to match explicitly on `ID` but rather just want the first field printed when there's any other field that matches `match`:

```
$ awk '{c=0; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /^match/) printf "%s%s%s", (c++ ? "" : $1), OFS, $i} c{print ""}' file
ID1 match1
ID2 match2 matchABC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try also

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i !~ /match|ID/) $i=""} 1' file1
ID1   match1 
ID2  match2 matchABC
```